# Qt safely remove a device

Tags: c++, qt, usb, qt5, removable-storage

I'm look for a way to safely remove my USB key from my Qt 5.2 application but I can't find any Qt module to do that.

Is their a way to do it or do I have to hardcode it ?

Comment: What do you mean by removing an usb key?

Comment: @LaszloPapp I mean something like [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/safely-remove-devices-from-your-computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean unmounting your usb device by removal, then there is no cross-platform solution for this. Perhaps there could be added something in the QtSystems module, however the problem is that this would require admin permission or some tricks, e.g. setuid or caps on Linux and so on.

You could do something along these lines to achieve this feature for now on your side:

```
void MyClass::unmount() {
#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
    // See details: http://linux.die.net/man/2/umount
    if (umount(myUsbKeyPath) < 0)
        qDebug() << "Failed to umount";
#elif Q_OS_WIN
    // See details: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;165721
    DWORD dwBytesReturned;
    DeviceIoControl(hVolume,
                    IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA,
                    NULL, 0,
                    NULL, 0,
                    &dwBytesReturned,
                    NULL);
#endif
}
```

Comment: That sounds great. Do you have the code for Mac Os part ?

Comment: @ꜱᴀᴍᴏᴛʜ: nope, sorry. Also, you may wish to do something like what pmount does to allow umounting as a regular user with setuid, etc. Also, you would need to use it in combination with QtSystems which returns the disk information, etc, because the information, e.g. path, is not necessarily cross-platform. It is a bit like serial port paths, etc.

Comment: @ꜱᴀᴍᴏᴛʜ: actually, linux parts could be working for Mac, too. Either way, I think you got the answer whether there is a way to do it or you need to code it. :)

Answer (score 2):

I've never removed USB using Qt but this simple c code will also work.

```
#include <sys/mount.h>

int umount(const char *target);
```